# How do I retrieve a value from a 2 dimensional list in Python

Tags: python, list

If I have a 2 dimensional list like this:

```
TopRow = [1, 3, 5]
MiddleRow = [7, 9, 11]
BottomRow = [13, 15, 17]
matrix = [TopRow, MiddleRow, BottomRow]
```

I need to make a function that takes in the 2 dimensional list and two values, row and col, as inputs, and then prints out the specified number in the specified row and collumn of the 2-dimensional list. Let's say row and col are defined like this:

```
row = 2
col = 3
```

Why doesn't this code retrieve the value (in this case, 11) and print it out?

```
def get_value(matrix, row, col):
    print(matrix[row][col])
```

Comment: Did you forget `list` are indexed from `0`?

Answer (score 7):

Python indexes start at 0, not 1.  11 is in row 1, column 2.

Answer (score 1):

Indices start at 0, so for your matrix, you have [0][0]...[2][2]

```
>>> TopRow = [1, 3, 5]
>>> MiddleRow = [7, 9, 11]
>>> BottomRow = [13, 15, 17]
>>> matrix = [TopRow, MiddleRow, BottomRow]
>>> 
>>> def get_value(matrix, row, col):
...     print(matrix[row][col])
... 
>>> get_value(matrix, 1, 2)
11
>>> get_value(matrix, 2, 1)
15
```

Comment: I think your answer is pretty clear without the final example (`get_value(matrix, 2, 1)`).